# Deleting column data in List Views

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a list view comprised of the following:

```
    // Add column headers for log
    logListView.View = View.Details;
    logListView.GridLines = true;
    logListView.FullRowSelect = true;
    logListView.Columns.Add("Event ID", 70);
    logListView.Columns.Add("Checkname", 150);
    logListView.Columns.Add("Hostname", 120);
    logListView.Columns.Add("Result", 150);
    logListView.Columns.Add("Date", 125);
    logListView.Columns.Add("Time", 125);
```

Each column holds data, although how would it be possible to delete all data in a specific column? (as illustrated below in the red box)

[image: Grid Image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want here. If you want to delete all the data in the column, why do you bind it in the first place? More information required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that column values to empty string:

```
int totalItems = logListView.Items.Count;
for(int i=0; i<totalItems ; i++){
    // Column B is at index 1
    logListView.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = string.Empty;
}
```